# Chrome strange behavior when wrapping table with table-layout: fixed

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, tablelayout

I have a div that wraps a table with `table-layout: fixed`.

```
<div class="wrap">  
    <table id="mytable"><tr>  
        <td>Some label</td>  
    </tr></table>  
</div>
```

The trouble is in that rendered DIV's width in Chrome is smaller that required to wrap my table. In Firefox it's ok.

[Here is the Fiddle demostration](http://jsfiddle.net/hBkT6/6/)

It is a Chrome bug?

Comment: Looks like Chrome bug, it makes the wrapper just 198px wide despite the content being 200px wide, perhaps because it incorrectly subtracts borders.